# How to adjust rowheight as per the contents in NPOI

Tags: c#, npoi

Using Npoi I am trying to achieve something like this in excel

> |Sample Text
>   |-------------------------------------|
>   |Sample Text1
>   |Sample Text2
>   |Sample Text3
>   |--------------------------------------|
>   |Sample Text4

If the height is specified like

> row.HeightInPoints = 60;

Then the row height gets fixed to that and each and every cell gets the same height

Incase

> sheet.GetRow(rowPosition).HeightInPoints = sheet.DefaultRowHeight;

is used then the sheet's most greatest height gets applied to the row.
How can we dynamically compute the row height and set its height such that other rows don't get effected.

I have used

> wraptext = true

and the cells are merged.
For differentiating them cell styles are being used as for like I have to render 3 rows of similar style but of different row height.
If I am using any of the above to set the row height then either I get the row height shrinked in case of text is more than the assigned height or the sample text and sample text 4 gets spaces around them as the row height gets set to the height of sample text1 sample text2 and sample text3

Comment: This mailing list item may help http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/Autosize-row-for-HSSF-library-td2308264.html

Comment: @GraemeMiller Thanks for replying, I had gone through the link earlier and could not get the solution till now. It is the same scenario of merged cells in my case too, as the mailing list being pointed out by you.

Comment: Cool. Glad you are getting somewhere.